# Scheduled tasks в java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, schedule

Есть **SpringBoot** app, и есть задача: организувать список задач которые будут запускаться в определенное время.

Вопрос существует ли масимально "*правильное*" (*да, я знаю что не существует одинаково "правильных" решений для всех задач, но все же*) решение ? Например что использовать для реализации RabbiMQ или стандартный "**ScheduledExecutorService**" и хранить информацию о задачах в БД ?

Суть вопроса состоит в том, как сейчас делают на продашене ?

Comment: [Так делают](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а что случается с пулом задач если приложение вырубается ? Там есть реализация резервного копирования задач или надо писать ? И да, огромное спасибо за совет!

Comment: В разделе 7.5 описан планировщик Quartz, он умеет сохранять задания.